# Show highest bid on auction

Tags: python, django

I want to show just the latest bid that someone makes on the auction listing but instead it shows me every Bid that has been made. I also want to do a function that doesn't allow bids lower than the actual highest bid.

models.py

```
class Bid(models.Model):
    auction =  models.ForeignKey(Auction, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="bids")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    new_bid = models.IntegerField()
```

views.py (I have the new_bid form already on the page of the auction)

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
def auction(request, id=id): 
    auction = Auction.objects.get(pk=id)
    new_bid = Bid.objects.last()
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PlaceNewBid(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = request.user
            new_bid = form.cleaned_data["new_bid"]
            comment = Bid(auction=auction, user=user, new_bid=new_bid)
            comment.save()     
    else:
        form = Lcreate()   
    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
        "form": PlaceNewBid,
        "comments": auction.comments.all(),
        "auction": auction,
        "bids": auction.bids.all(),
        "new_bid": new_bid
        
    })
```

forms.py

```
class PlaceNewBid(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bid
        fields = ('new_bid',)
```

html

````
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {%csrf_token%}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Place a New Bid</button>
                {{form.as_p}}
            </form>
            {%for bid in bids%}
            <h3>${{ bid.new_bid}}</h3>
            {%empty%}
            No offers yet.
            {%endfor%}
            {{auction.description}}
       ```  
I hope everything is understandable, thanks
````

Answer (score 1):

To limit the bid amount you can simply use the form's validation method:

```
class PlaceNewBid(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bid
        fields = ('new_bid',) 
    
    def clean_new_bid(self):
        bid = self.cleaned_data.get('new_bid')
        # get the top bid
        top_bid = Bid.objects.order_by("-new_bid").first()
         if not top_bid:
             return bid

        # compare the bid with the top bid
        if bid <= top_bid.new_bid:
            raise ValidationError("Your bid is too small!")
```

And to just show the last bid:

First, you need to get the last bid and pass it to the template (you're passing all the bids):

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
def auction(request, id=id): 
    ... 
    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
        ....
        "last_bid": auction.bids.order_by("-new_bid").first(),
        ...
    
    })
```

And then show the last one (No need to use a for loop):

```
<h3>${{ last_bid.new_bid}}</h3>
```

Comment: Hi, I get this error. 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'new_bid'

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: Sorry, now I get this error. local variable 'new_bid' referenced before assignment

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from this code? where does it say the error is?

Comment: I found what was causing the error was the ' "new_bid": new_bid ' line on views.py. But now the form doesn't work. I click the button but it doesn't do anything

Comment: That's probably because your deleted `new_bid = Bid.objects.last()` from your view. Anyway, it has nothing to do with the code I wrote for you. Also, you can save the form instead of creating a `Bid` instance in your view.